# PHP XMLReader - how to parse these children?

Tags: php, xmlreader

This is part of my XML:

```
<group name="General">
  <property name="Farbe">rosa</property>
  <property name="Breite (mm)">169</property>
  <property name="...">...</property>
</group>
```

In my code, I am looking at the node names, like this:

```
if($nodeName == 'group') {
    // How to get the children here with attributes and values?
}
```

I tried using `SimpleXMLElement`, but that did not work.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Using DOMDocument you could probably iterate through the xml like this ( not tested ):

```
$strxml='<group name="General">
  <property name="Farbe">rosa</property>
  <property name="Breite (mm)">169</property>
</group>';


$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML( $strxml );

$colgroups=$dom->getElementsByTagName('group');
if( $colgroups ){
    foreach( $colgroups as $group ){
        echo $group->getAttribute('name');

        if( $group->childNodes->length ){
            foreach( $group->childNodes as $child ){
                if( $child->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE ) echo $child->tagName.' '.$child->getAttribute('name').' '.$child->nodeValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode` combined with `json_encode` and `simplexml_load_string`

**Parse the xml as array**

```
$result ='<group name="General">
  <property name="Farbe">rosa</property>
  <property name="Breite (mm)">169</property>
</group>';
//Will convert Object data to array
function objectToArray($object){
     return json_decode(json_encode($object),true,512,0);
}

$xml = objectToArray(simplexml_load_string($result));

echo '<pre>';print_r($xml);echo '</pre>';
echo $xml['@attributes']['name'];//outputs General
echo $xml['property'][0];//outputs rosa
echo $xml['property'][1];//outputs 169
```

**Parse the xml string as an object of  SimpleXMLElement**

```
$result ='<group name="General">
  <property name="Farbe">rosa</property>
  <property name="Breite (mm)">169</property>
</group>';
$xml2 = simplexml_load_string($result);
echo '<pre>';print_r($xml2);echo '</pre>';
echo $xml2->attributes();


echo $xml2->property[0];//outputs rosa
echo $xml2->property[1];//outputs 169
```